# How to open new activity using onItemClick

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have an onItemClick listener. There's no error, but every time I click on "Caloocan" in my ListView nothing happens.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        restauLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                int value = (int) restauLV.getItemAtPosition(position);

                if (value == 0){

                    Intent cal = new Intent(HopNow.this, caloocan.class);
                    startActivity(cal);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code for caloocan.java

```
package com.example.aspiree1_472g.finalfirstpage;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class caloocan  extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.caloocan);


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use custom row layout for listview adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    restauLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0){
                Intent cal = new Intent(HopNow.this, caloocan.class);
                startActivity(cal);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: my pleasure :) happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom row layout. Do the following

you need to do 2 steps in your e.g: `listview_item.xml`

1. set the root layout with:

   ```
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
   ```
2. set any focusable or clickable view in this item with:

   ```
   android:clickable="false"   
   android:focusable="false"   
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   ```